# Rails 4 delete association for empty nested attributes when updating parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a model **House** that belongs to a **User**. **House** has_many **cars**. In my models, i've declared the necessary **accepts_nested_attributes_for**, and my nested attributes have the appropriate _attributes and id fields.

I want to be able to disassociate my **Car** model from **House**, but not **User**.

Let's say I have a saved **House** object like this:

`"house" => {"owner" => "bob, "car_attributes" => [{"id" => 1, "type" => "toyota"},{"id" => 2, "type" => "honda"}]}`

I want to remove (but not delete) a car object from **House** and update it so it looks like this:

`"house" => {"owner" => "bob, "car_attributes" => [{"id" => 1, "type" => "toyota"}]}`

Obviously when I call `@house.update_attributes({"owner" => "bob, "car_attributes" => [{"id" => 1, "type" => "toyota"}]})`, the `belongs_to` association is not removed. Is there any simple way to disassociate a car object from its parent?

Looking through the Rails documentation, there is a collection method `delete` that does just that -i.e sets the parent foreign keys to `null`. The problem is, I would have to mark each object I want to dissassociate in the client, send it over, then walk through each nested attribute and call `delete()` manually where necessary, which doesn't seem very railsy to me.

Is there an easier way to update a parent model by disassociating (without destroying) its nested attributes in rails?

Comment: If you remove the Car's association to its House then it will be an orphaned Car object right? I ask because I wonder if that's really OK? I wouldn't think it would be. If it should be OK then I'd expect there to be a join model between a Car and a House (i.e. Cars are selected from a list and the list is kept relatively constant). So why not just destroy the Car?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, car also belongs_to user, so it wouldn't get orphaned

Comment: Any luck with this one?